# Calling a function with a dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have this code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<a onclick="return myFunction('.$row['value']'.')"></a>';
}
```

I need to use that dynamic parameter in a function like this:

```
function myFunction(my_value){
 alert('This is my value' + my_value);
 return true;
}
```

But the function is not called because of that parameter.Does anyone why?

Comment: in the parameter, is that an integer? or a string? quote it :)

Comment: @Ghost , it's a string , actually it's more like a directory path: doc/docx/doc.txt

Comment: make sure function comes before it's used. Also, what Ghost said, add quotes

Comment: Check the HTML/JS that's being output. It has syntax errors. Read the duplicate for good ways to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error, it should be this:

`echo '<a onclick="return myFunction('.$row['value'].')"></a>';`

Also if your value is a string value you need to use quotes:

`echo '<a onclick="return myFunction(\''.addslashes($row['value']).'\')"></a>';`

Comment: actually the syntax error was just here,i forgot to add that quote , but i didnt knew the second one.I'll give it a try

Comment: yes,that was the problem,thank you!